# In Asp.net, 'Post' Ajax Request Will 'Get'

Tags: asp.net, ajax, post, get

In my Asp.net Project and in Controller with name 'AjaxController' I have this Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetList(int year)
{
  var res="";
  // some codes 
  return Json(res);
}
```

And in Js file :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Ajax/GetList/',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    data: 2000,
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
    // some codes  
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    },
});
```

I expect that this method ONLY called with 'POST' but when I check My logs I will see some errors like:

```
AbsoluteUri :https://example.com/Ajax/GetList/
* Message :A public action method 'GetList' was not found on controller 'Controllers.AjaxController'.
```

That shows Called as 'GET', NOT 'POST'.
What and where is problem?
Thancks In Advanced

Comment: Answer Please. NONE of answers in stackoverflow to question like this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions from my end -

- Remove contentType and async attributes unless really required
- Pass JSON object to 'data'
- Also, use debugger and breakpoints generously to figure out yourself where your code is going astray

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Ajax/GetList/',
    type: "POST",
    //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    data: {year: 2000},
    //async: false,
    success: function (response) {
    debugger;
    // some codes  
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        debugger;
        alert(error);
    },
});
```